# Subsets subspaces rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

Let $\varphi: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ be the rotation around the line through the origin and the point
$(1, 1, 1)$ by 120 degrees. Decompose $\Bbb R^3$ as a direct sum of two subspaces that are each stable under $\varphi$.

This is the exercise. So I though that this answer is good??? But I am not sure though. I am really doubthful about it.

My answer:

Let $\varphi: \Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$ be a rotation around the line through the origin and the point $(1,1,0)$ by 60 degrees. Also let $\lambda : \Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$ be the rotation through the points $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$ by 60 degrees. Then their sum equals the rotation that is described above?

Comment: You're writing the rotation as the sum of two rotations. You need to write the space as the sum of two subspaces.

Comment: So I am correcting it right when I let lambda be the rotation though the line (0,0,1) and the origin?

Comment: I don't know what "correcting it right" means, but you sure didn't answer the question correctly.  Again, you're giving the wrong *kind* of answer.

Comment: Hmmm then I do not really understand the question. :(

Comment: You're asked to write $\Bbb R^3=U\oplus V$ where $U$ and $V$ are stable by $\varphi$. This is very different from writing $\phi$ as a sum of 2 rotations. Is it clear ?

Comment: Try looking through the textbook to figure out what a "direct sum of spaces" is supposed to mean.  Try looking up "direct sum" in the index.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for a decomposition $R^3 = U \oplus V$ such that $\phi(U) \subset U$ and $\phi(V) \subset V$.

Hint: What happens to the axis of rotation (a one-dimensional subspace) under $\phi$? What is a complementary subspace of the axis of rotation that is also invariant under $\phi$?